# Reading a sequence of data from program memory - AVR ATmega16

Tags: assembly, avr, atmega

I'm writing this code in assembly for AVR ATmega16 microcontroller using AtmelStudio 7. I'm trying to read some data from program memory and using them. I know that i have to use Z register to point the program memory and the pre-stored data is recognized by the label "BCDTo7_Seg" by the assembler. It does read the first number in that table(I can see this procedure using the debugger) but, when i post increment the Z register the address increases but the read value is still the same! Hope someone could help me out. Here is a part of the code:

```
    /* Simply start reading from program memory */
    /* The reading from program memory must be done with the starting address: BCDTo7_Seg LABEL */

    /* INITIALIZE Z POINTER */
    ldi ZH,high(BCDTo7_Seg << 1)
    ldi ZL,low(BCDTo7_Seg << 1)
    clr R23
    /* R23 contains the data must be written to the 7 segment */
    /* Post Increment Z after reading each number */
    lpm R23,Z+
    /* decrement R16 */
    dec R16
    /* Check the loop end point */
    brne R_W
    rjmp start
```

Comment: I'm assuming the answer by @nopasara is correct but as the `start` label that you jump to is not included in your program snippet it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time it executes it sets pointer at the beginning.

```
ldi ZH,high(BCDTo7_Seg << 1)
ldi ZL,low(BCDTo7_Seg << 1)
```